# Injecting parameters from URL to reverse proxy via proxy_set_header

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm passing a cookie to the remote server using the following block:

```
location /
{
    set $foo "bla=mla";
    set $bar "$arg_user=$arg_pass";

    proxy_pass http://remoteserver:8117/;
    proxy_connect_timeout 3600s;
    proxy_read_timeout 3600s;
    proxy_send_timeout 3600s;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_cache_bypass 1; 
    proxy_no_cache 1;
    proxy_hide_header Set-Cookie;
    proxy_ignore_headers Set-Cookie;
    proxy_set_header Cookie "$foo";
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Origin http://$host;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    add_header X-uri "$foo";
}
```

This works fine.

However, when I try to build the $foo using the arguments in the URL, it fails.

Example URL:

http://localserver/test?user=bla&pass=mla

Config Change:

`proxy_set_header Cookie "$bar";`

X-uri test header has the exact same value for both $foo and $bar.

Comment: With add_header X-uri "$foo"; , how can X-uri have the value of $bar?

Comment: I change it to $bar when I set proxy_set_header Cookie "$bar";